# file_validate_size doesn't seem to work

Tags: hooks, blocks, forms

I'm currently learning how to make a custom module that creates a block with a textfield and upload field. So far so good, only thing is: Drupal doesn't seem to respect my file_validate_size value.

Here's my block_configure code:

```
   $form['file_link'] = array(
        '#type'         => 'managed_file',
        '#title'        => t('My upload field'),
        '#size'         => 60,
        '#description'  => t('Select a file.'),
        '#upload_location' => 'public://',
        '#default_value' => variable_get('file_link'),
        '#upload_validators' => array('file_validate_extensions' => array(),
                                'file_validate_size' => array(26214400)
                                ),
   );
```

Most file_validate_size examples that i've found used bytes instead of megabytes. I don't know if this is a must? file_validate_extensions works perfectly though. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: According to the docs here https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_validate_size/7 file_validate_size wont run if you are user 1

Comment: yes, I also read that but that's not true. I've got it working now and tested it by uploading something with an admin and a normal user account. In both occasions Drupal gave an error if a file is above 26214400 (25 MB) bytes. So it does respect my file_validate_size.

My problem was is that I had to higher my post_max_size 4M value in .htaccess. I only did that with upload_max_filesize.

Maybe this information comes in handy for someone that's experiencing the same problem. Please check the .htaccess file first!

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem to respect"? What really happened? what you expected to happen?

Comment: I am not getting any validation errors thought I am validating it against array(0.01 * 1024 * 1024) i. e. 10KB. and my .htaccess file allows uploading files more than this.